# How to extract information about a frame that's being rendered for later use?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, mathematics

Is there a way to extract information (calculations) about a frame that's being rendered without rendering it? Namely, send all calculations that Blender is doing when rendering a frame, to an external text file that can be used later without having to run Blender?

This could make it easier for less powerful PCs to render heavy scenes as they wouldn't need to open the `.blend` file.

Comment: Seems like you're describing "headless" mode where the GUI and scene isn't rendered on the screen. Blender does have such a thing, it's called background mode, please see for example https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31255/can-blender-render-on-systems-without-a-gui

Comment: @kheetor That wasn't really what I meant. I'm wondering how (if it's impossible) I can exctract the information Blender gets when rendering a frame so I can send that information further to client that doesn't have Blender installled.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure you cannot help rendering at all if you don't have full access to all the assets that are being used in the scene. You need to have the models, textures and animations etc. loaded in memory to be able to process raycasting and sampling. That is the bare minimum and not coincidentally it's exactly what Blender's background mode does :)